# Why is this array not working correctly?

Tags: java

Why is this array not working?

I'm taking Java as a class and this array isn't working, can you let me know why it's not working? I would have searched if this question was already asked, but I think it's just a super basic question and I don't think anyone has asked it before.

Here's the array:

```
class identify
{
    public static void main(String arge[]);
    {
        int a[]= new a[4];
        a[]={12,14,15,17,21};
        System.out.println(a[3]);
        System.out.println(a[4]);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/cvD1I7

Comment: Lose the semicolon at the end of your `main` method declaration.

Comment: You are also allocating memory for only 4 items, and then trying to put 5 items in the array? Are you trying to redeclare `a` as an array that holds those 5 elements?

Comment: You should also look at this stackoverflow answer for how to declare an array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in your code:

- **Declaration**: The assignment operator `=` has two operands: right-side, which is the variable receiving the value, and left-side, which is the value being assigned. The left-side expression must construct an array. You will probably note that `new a[4]` isn't a valid construction for an array. It should be `new int[4]` instead.
- **Initialization**: The `{x,y,...}` syntax can only be used when initializing an array. `new int[x];` will allocate a new array with capacity/length `x`, and initialize every element in the array with a default value (`0` in the case of `int`s). Once there, you can not initialize the array again with constant values with the `{x,y,z}` construct.

Also, the way you've declared the array (`int a[]`) is discouraged, use `int[] a` instead. It's a clearer syntax.

Try this:

```
int[] a = new int[]{ 12,14,15,17,21};
```

Note you could also have done:

```
// Declaring a is an array of ints
int[] a;                         
// Initialization and assignment to a. 
// Notice the array length isn't explicitly given.
a = new int[]{ 12,14,15,17,21 };
```

Or else:

```
// Declaring a is an array of ints
int[] a;                         
// Initializing a as an empty array with 5 elements (all of them will be 0)
a = new int[5];
a[0] = 12;
a[1] = 14;
a[2] = 15;
a[3] = 17;
a[4] = 21;
```

You might find the [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) page of the Java Tutorials useful.

**EDIT** As a side note, as rgettman pointed out in his comment, there shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of the `void` method signature. And take into account that if you allocate a `new int[4]`, the last valid index to access it will be 3 (`a[3]`). `a[4]` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

a[] is not a variable.  try this:

`a = new int[]{12,14,15,17,21};`

Comment: also you could simply combine those lines:

`int[] a = new int[] {12,14,15,17,21};`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 int a[]= new int[]{12,14,15,17,21};// initialization at the time of declaration
```

or you can use

```
    int[] a;    //declaration

  a = new int[]{12,14,15,17,21};  // then initialization
```